# Why is my sidebar all the way down?

Tags: html, css, css-float, sidebar

I'm trying to replicate 9gag front page just for practice. And i can't understand why is my sidebar all the way down. I am sure there must be some simple answer, but i just can't figure it out.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif, serif;
}

nav {
        background: #000;
}

.logo {
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;  
}

.logo img {
    max-height: 46px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: -40px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.BigNav {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.BigNav a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #333;
}

.BigNav a {
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.SmallNav {
    margin-left: -30px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.SmallNav a {
    color: #999;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.SmallNav a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}

.notification {
    float: right;
    height: 50px;  
}

.notification img {
    max-height: 30px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search {
    float: right;
    height: 50px;  
}

.search img {
    max-height: 24px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.profile {
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.profile img {
    max-height: 46px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.upload {
    color: #FFF;
    float: right;
    background: #0099FF;
    padding: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.upload:hover {
   background: #13AAFF;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 66%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}

.post {
    width: 66%;
    float: left;
}

.post img {
    width: 550px;
    height: auto;
}

.aside {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

.aside img {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-1.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript-1.js"></script>
    <title>9 GAG</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo.png">
            </div>
<!--Menu-->              
            <ul class="BigNav">
                <li><a href="#">Hot</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trending</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fresh</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sections▾</a></li>                
            </ul>
            <ul class="SmallNav">
                <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cosplay</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Girl</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Comic</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NSFW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GIF</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WTF</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Geeky</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ʕ •ᴥ• ʔ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Anime & Manga</a></li>
            </ul>
<!--Right side icons-->            
            <div class="upload">
                <p> + Upload </p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="profile">
                <img src="person-flat.png">
            </div>
            
            <div class="notification">
                <img src="not.png">
            </div>
            
            <div class="search">
                <img src="search.png">
            </div>
            
        </nav>
    </header>
<!--Content area-->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="post">
        <h3>I know I'm a douche for wearing sunglasses at night but...</h3>
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a77Pzr2_700b.jpg">
    </div>
        <div class="post">
        <h3>I know I'm a douche for wearing sunglasses at night but...</h3>
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a77Pzr2_700b.jpg">
    </div>
        <div class="post">
        <h3>I know I'm a douche for wearing sunglasses at night but...</h3>
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a77Pzr2_700b.jpg">
    </div>
        <div class="post">
        <h3>I know I'm a douche for wearing sunglasses at night but...</h3>
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a77Pzr2_700b.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="aside">
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/ao9dLpe_700b_v1.jpg">
        <h4>Comment your country's favourite hangover food!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="aside">
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/ao9dLpe_700b_v1.jpg">
        <h4>Comment your country's favourite hangover food!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="aside">
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/ao9dLpe_700b_v1.jpg">
        <h4>Comment your country's favourite hangover food!</h4>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

So yeah, i need to add some text because there's too much code. Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: In future, please only paste the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="posts" style="
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
">
    <div class="post">
        <h3>I know I'm a douche for wearing sunglasses at night but...</h3>
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a77Pzr2_700b.jpg">
    </div>
        <div class="post">
        <h3>I know I'm a douche for wearing sunglasses at night but...</h3>
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a77Pzr2_700b.jpg">
    </div>
        <div class="post">
        <h3>I know I'm a douche for wearing sunglasses at night but...</h3>
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a77Pzr2_700b.jpg">
    </div>
        <div class="post">
        <h3>I know I'm a douche for wearing sunglasses at night but...</h3>
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a77Pzr2_700b.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side" style="
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
">
    <div class="aside">
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/ao9dLpe_700b_v1.jpg">
        <h4>Comment your country's favourite hangover food!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="aside">
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/ao9dLpe_700b_v1.jpg">
        <h4>Comment your country's favourite hangover food!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="aside">
        <img src="http://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/ao9dLpe_700b_v1.jpg">
        <h4>Comment your country's favourite hangover food!</h4>
    </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

just give some margin-top to side bar..........

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all the posts in their own container, and all the asides in another container, both within your wrapper. Apply 100% width to your wrapper, and assign relative widths to your two containers and float the main div left, and sidebar div right. (if you want the sidebar in the middle of the space between the main div and the right edge of the screen then float them both left.)

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CZorio13/7c6u5hrj/1/) (using your code) as an example. You still need to change the scaling to your needs, but this shows the concept.

Relevant code:

```
.main{
  float:left;
  width:60%;
}

.sidebar{
  float:right;
  width:30%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This ganna solve your problem

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="posts">
     <div class="post">
       ....
     </div>
     <div class="post">
       ....
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="aside">
    <div class="aside-item">
       ....
     </div>
     <div class="aside-item">
       ....
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

.posts{width:66%; float:left;}
.aside{widht:34%; float:left;}
.post,.aside-item{width:100%;}
```